# Пирамидальная сортировка на с++

Tags: c++, массивы, методы

Хочу сделать сортировку пирамидальную (обратную) То есть что бы массив в котором есть числа 4,5,3,0 отсортировало не так 0,3,4,5, а так 5,4,3,0.
Вот функции для нахождения(от меньшего к большому)

```
template<typename T>
void downHeap(T a[], long k, long n)
{
    T new_elem;
    long number;
    new_elem = a[k];

    while(k <= n/2)
{
        number = 2*k;
        if( number < n && a[number] < a[number+1] )
            number++;
        if( new_elem >= a[number] ) break;
        // иначе
        a[k] = a[number];
        k = number;
    }
    a[k] = new_elem;
}
template<typename T>
void heapSort(T a[], long size)
{
    long i;
    T temp;
    for(i=size/2-1; i >= 0; i--) downHeap(a, i, size-1);
    for(i=size-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        temp=a[i]; a[i]=a[0]; a[0]=temp;
        downHeap(a, 0, i-1);
         }
}
```

Comment: ну так поменяйте все знаки на противоположные... `if( number < n && a[number] > a[number+1] )` `new_elem <= a[number]`. А вообще странный вопрос, если вы всё это сами написали.

Comment: И аккуратно проверьте что будет если не степени 2 кое-где будут. Первый цикл подозрительный, ещё и выходы за пределы массива.

Comment: @pavel не мой... не дало изменений